# QGIS server: use of FILTER clause with boolean values

Tags: qgis-server, feature-filter

I have set up a QGIS server (3.4) to serve WMS layers with a PostGIS database.
The WMS queries include a dynamically created `FILTER` clause.

However, the [official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html) is quite lacking explanations for the `FILTER` clause and I have troubles with filtering based on boolean attributes.

I want to filter based on `zico IS true` where, in the PostGIS database, *zico* is a boolean field of the table *locations*.

I have tried:

```
http://qgis.localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/qgis/projects/my_qgis_project.qgs&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=locations&styles=&format=image/png&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&srs=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&crs=EPSG:3857&bbox=2504688.5428486555,3757032.8142729844,3757032.814272984,5009377.085697314&FILTER=locations:%22zico%22%20IS%20True
```

i.e. including  `FILTER:locations:'zico' IS True` in the query to the WMS server,
for which the server response was the standard error message

> The filter string "zico" IS False has been rejected because of
> security reasons. Note: Text strings have to be enclosed in single or
> double quotes. A space between each word / special character is
> mandatory. Allowed Keywords and special characters are
> IS,NOT,NULL,AND,OR,IN,=,<,>=,>,>=,!=,',',(,),DMETAPHONE,SOUNDEX. Not
> allowed are semicolons in the filter expression.

What is the proper syntax for `FILTER` with boolean attributes?

Comment: I managed to make the query work with ``` FILTER:locations:'zico' = 'True' ```, which rather looks transtyping than properly querying a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following(double quote):

```
locations:"zico" IS True
```

Comment: Tne filter is the same as the syntax in the field calculator. This means that we put the names of the columns in " "